# swift play video from the gallery

Tags: swift, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

I wish to play video from local library to my MPMoviePlayerController.
If I put the video to my bundle it will work

```
let selURL = "sample"
let pathToEx1 = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource( selURL, ofType: "mp4")
```

but if it is from the library it is not.

```
    let selURL = "file:///Users/Vinod/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/G3G533F0-E16A-40DB-A6F1-GH67GFR89AF/data/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/sample.mp4"
let pathToEx1 = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource( selURL, ofType: "mp4")
```

The second code fails. How can I run video from the gallery or my folders?

Answer (score 0):

To use the user's photo/video library, use UIImagePickerController and you will get back a video URL:

```
    @IBAction func selectImageFromPhotoLibrary(sender: AnyObject) {
        imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        imagePickerController.delegate = self
        imagePickerController.mediaTypes = ["public.movie"]
        present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    extension ViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
            let videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? NSURL
        }
    }
```

Otherwise if you are reading and writing videos and not saving them to the photolibrary most likely you would put them in the documents directory, since iOS is sandboxed and there are very few places you can write to.

Comment: I am using Fusuma for the image/video options.
https://github.com/ytakzk/Fusuma
It do not have direct use of UIImagePickerController.   It has the option to bring images from library and videos from camera, not videos from the library.